# I want to figure out the error - TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

Good afternoon.

Announced the ADX indicator function 
(link Python: Average Directional Index (ADX) 2 Directional Movement System Calculation - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=joOWm-GcHTw).

An error occurs during operation - "TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable".

on this line - 
    TRDate,TrueRange = TR(date[x],closep[x],highp[x],lowp[x],openp[x],closep[x-1])
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

I will be glad of any help. 
Thank. 
The code is below.

```
def TR(d,c,h,l,o,yc):
    x = h-l
    y = abs(h-yc)
    z = abs(l-yc)


    if y <= x >= z:
        TR = x
    elif x <= y >= z:
        TR = y
    elif x <= z >= y:
        TR = z
    return d, TR



def DM(d,o,h,l,c,yo,yh,yl,yc):
    moveUp = h-yh
    moveDown = yl-l

    if 0 < moveUp > moveDown:
        PDM = moveUp
    else:
        PDM = 0

    if 0 < moveDown > moveUp:
        NDM = moveDown
    else:
        NDM = 0
    return d,PDM,NDM

def calcDIs(date,openp,highp,lowp,closep,openpy,highpy,lowpy,closepy,tf):
    x = 1
    TRDates = []
    TrueRanges = []
    PosDMs = []
    NegDMs = []

    while x < len(date):
        TRDate,TrueRange = TR(date[x],closep[x],highp[x],lowp[x],openp[x],closep[x-1]) << error
        TRDates.append(TRDate)
        TrueRanges.append(TrueRange)

        DMdate,PosDM,NegDM = DM(date[x],openp[x],highp[x],lowp[x],closep[x],openp[x-1],highp[x-1],lowp[-1],closep[x-1]) << I assume that there will be the same error
        PosDMs.append(PosDM)
        NegDMs.append(NegDM)

        x +=1



    expPosDM = ExpMovingAverage(PosDMs,14)
    expNegDM = ExpMovingAverage(NegDMs,14)
    ATR = ExpMovingAverage(TrueRanges,14)


    xx = 0
    PDIs = []
    NDIs = []


    while xx < len(ATR):
        PDI = 100*(expPosDM[xx]/ATR[xx])
        PDIs.append(PDI)


        NDI = 100*(expNegDM[xx]/ATR[xx])
        NDIs.append(NDI)

        xx +=1


    return PDIs,NDIs
```

Comment: Could you give an example of how do you call `calcDIs` ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I did not insert the last part of the code.

```
def ADX(date,openp,highp,lowp,closep,openpy,highpy,lowpy,closepy,tf,tfy):
    PositiveDI,NegativeDI = calcDIs(date,openp,highp,lowp,closep,openpy,highpy,lowpy,closepy,tf)


    xxx = 0
    DXs =[]

    while xxx < len(date[1:]):
        DX = 100*( (abs(PositiveDI[xxx]-NegativeDI[xxx])
                    /(PositiveDI[xxx]+NegativeDI[xxx])))


        DXs.append(DX)

        xxx += 1


    ADX = ExpMovingAverage(DXs,14)

    return PositiveDI, NegativeDI, ADX
```

And accordingly the call:

```
PositiveDI, NegativeDI, ADX = ta.ADX(data,open,high,low,closes,open,high,low,closes,14,14)
```

- here data on candles received through API Binance - https://api.binance.com/api/v1/klines?symbol=LTCBTC&interval=5m

eg:
[
  [
    1499040000000,      // data
    "0.01634790",       // Open
    "0.80000000",       // High
    "0.01575800",       // Low
    "0.01577100",       // Close
    "148976.11427815",  // volume
    1499644799999,      // Closing time
    "2434.19055334",    // Quota currency
    308,                // Number of deals
    "1756.87402397",    // Taker buy base asset volume
    "28.46694368",      // Taker buy quote asset volume
    "17928899.62484339" // Ignore
  ]
]

Answer (score 0):

Can you show all your import statements?

Also can you change your `date` variable to something else?

Comment: No, I can’t change the DATE variable. It was used in the premiere, which I indicated on the link (see the first post).

Comment: What kind of variables (import statements) are we talking about, I did not understand what needs to be shown? 
Download data on candles from the exchange?

Comment: change the name of this variable here

    def calcDIs(date) 

to

    def calcDIs(curr_date)

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon. Did as suggested. Did not help.

```
def calcDIs(cur_date,openp,highp,lowp,closep,openpy,highpy,lowpy,closepy,tf):
    x = 1
    TRDates = []
    TrueRanges = []
    PosDMs = []
    NegDMs = []

    while x < len(cur_date):
        TRDate,TrueRange = TR(cur_date[x],closep[x],highp[x],lowp[x],openp[x],closep[x-1])
```

All the same error.
    TRDate,TrueRange = TR(cur_date[x],closep[x],highp[x],lowp[x],openp[x],closep[x-1])
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable